# Why was the featured tag removed on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

The [featured](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag, a special moderator-only tag, had been on several entries (such as the FAQ and a post about how to use LaTeX) and is now gone.  It caused those tagged entries to show on the parent site, in the right side bar when viewing a question.  With no entries tagged, that side bar panel shows the few most recent questions on meta.  Was it removed intentionally?  Why?

Comment: @Isaac: do you remember which posts were tagged with featured? I can re-tag those. (Will do so for the LaTeX one as soon as I find it. But I don't know which FAQ one you are referring to.)

Comment: Perhaps what we need is a readme tag with its own space on the main page. Given that featured is supposed to be short-lived.

Comment: @Willie: I don't know that I remember specifically all of them (and chances are if we can't figure out which one it was, it probably shouldn't be featured), but at least the two I had in mind were almost certainly tagged `(faq-proposed)`.  Perhaps: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-do-i-learn-about-markup http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange

Comment: @Willie: In actuality, though somewhat tangential to my original question, what should really happen (and is more important than the featured tag) is some cleanup of questions here that should become the FAQ (with the special moderator-only `(faq)` tag).  Specifically, have a look at [the FAQ on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), by which I mean the index and organized set of faq-tagged questions there (as opposed to the brief FAQ linked at the top of every page).

Comment: @Moron: I think using the featured tag is appropriate and that having to come back to it every so often is probably a good thing; I also suspect that almost anything that you'd tag as you were thinking ought to be tagged `(faq)` and indexed and cross-linked as on meta.SO (see my immediately-previous comment in reply to Willie Wong).

Comment: @Isaac: Faq/Readme whatever you call it. These are permanent and ought to be read by all (at any time). I am guessing Featured are probably for the current 'hot' topics on meta and could lose significance over time.

Comment: @Isaac: I don't think I quite have the time right now (the next few weeks) to clean-up the FAQ. (I've been sorta wondering about...) Now that it is pointed out to me I'll get around to doing it in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @Isaac: instead of keeping those questions as featured (which requires bumping every month), I think a better idea is, like you said, to make some of the faq-proposed actually faqs.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent long-term staleness, the featured tag will only remain on a meta post for a maximum of 30 days.

You can re-tag the question with featured and it should stay featured for another 30 days.

Comment: Would it make sense for meta questions tagged `(faq)` or whichever meta question becomes the index for those questions to somehow have priority over questions-in-general in filling those slots after feature-tagged questions are used up?

Comment: @isaac no because those would simply be stale as well